# embed a unique, editable google spreadsheet

Tags: iframe, google-sheets, embed

I have a (rather complicated) spreadsheet.  It has one UI tab, where the user can make selection from dropdowns, and another seven or so data tabs that feed into the UI tab.

The sheet itself is a ship configuration tool, for the video game 'Star Citizen'.

As the sheet allows users to customize each item on their ship, I am hoping to find a way to embed the sheet into a webpage, but to have it unique to each user.

Alternately, can anyone recommend any way to create a UI of sorts on a webpage itself, that would reference back to the data collected in the sheet?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

David